# SyntaxError: can't assign to literal, while running code to count number of vowels in string

Tags: python

i am testing a code that counts the number of vowels in a string, but it always gives me a SyntaxError. It's probably something really stupid that I missed, but I have no idea where it is coming from.
Here is my code:

```
def count_vowels(string):
num_vowels = 0


for 'a' in string:

    num_vowels += 1

for 'e' in string:

    num_vowels += 1

for 'i' in string:

    num_vowels += 1

for 'o' in string:

    num_vowels += 1

for 'u' in string:

    num_vowels += 1

print(num_vowels)

count_vowels('abracadabra')
count_vowels("")
count_vowels("pear tree")
count_vowels("o a kak ushakov lil vo kashu kakao")
count_vowels("tk r n m kspkvgiw qkeby lkrpbk u thouonm fiqqb kxe...(This just goes on forever"))
```

Here is error code:

```
for 'a' in string: (line7)
   ^
SytntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Comment: I have already tried putting all the vowels in a list, but it just gives me a wierd number and i have no idea why.

Comment: What do you intend ``for 'a' in string`` to mean? A ``for`` loop works as ``for <target> in <iterable>:``, where ``<target>`` is *assigned* the next value from ``<iterable>`` on each iteration step.

Comment: `def count_vowels(s): return sum(s.count(v) for v in 'aeiou')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for 'a' in string` is not the right way to look for occurrences of `a` in a string.

The syntax `for item in list` requires `item` to be a variable, and you have a literal value instead, which is why you're getting that error.

Use this instead:

```
for char in string:
    if char in "aeiou":
        num_vowels += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes...

```py
def count_vowels(string):
    num_vowels = 0
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for letter in string:
        if letter in vowels:
            num_vowels += 1
    print(num_vowels)


count_vowels('abracadabra')
count_vowels("")
count_vowels("pear tree")
count_vowels("o a kak ushakov lil vo kashu kakao")
count_vowels("tk r n m kspkvgiw qkeby lkrpbk u thouonm fiqqb kxe...(This just goes on forever"))
```

You can look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) for some theory.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your for-loops.

```
for 'a' in string:
```

A for-loop is for traversing an iterable.  A for-loop assigns values from an iterable to its loop variable.  You've tried to give the name `'a'` to the loop variable, which is a literal string not an identifier.  It needs to be an identifier.

The simplest way of counting a single character within a string withing python would be to use `.count()`:

```
'reed'.count('e') // returns 2
```

A better way that counts any vowel:

```
sum(1 for c in string if c in 'aeiou')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax problem. `for` wants a variable because it is intended to iterate over an iterable of values. Assuming that you want to count *distinct* vowels, you could use `if`:

```
if 'a' in string:
    num_vowels += 1
```

But the idiomatic way would be:

```
count_vowels = sum(1 if i in string else 0 for i in 'aeiou')
```

(read about *comprehensions* for that syntax)

Comment: I may be misreading the OP's intent, but I think the count of vowels in `'foo'` is supposed to be 2.  Your comprehension would give 1.  Also that `else` is a problem.

Comment: `unique_vowels = sum(i in string for i in 'aeiou')`. But I don't think the OP was aiming for that.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Time for me to have a break, my code was plain wrong... It now gives the count of unique vowels in a Pythonic style

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_vowels(string):
    num_vowels = 0
    if 'a' in string:
        num_vowels += 1
    if 'e' in string:
        num_vowels += 1
    if 'i' in string:
        num_vowels += 1
    if 'o' in string:
        num_vowels += 1
    if 'u' in string:
        num_vowels += 1
    print(num_vowels)

count_vowels('abracadabra')
count_vowels("")
count_vowels("pear tree")
count_vowels("o a kak ushakov lil vo kashu kakao")
count_vowels("tk r n m kspkvgiw qkeby lkrpbk u thouonm fiqqb kxe...(This just goes on forever)")
```

For the completion of your code,

```
def count_vowels(string):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    num_vowels = 0
    for vowel in vowels:
        num_vowels += string.count(vowel)
    print(num_vowels)

count_vowels('abracadabra')
count_vowels("")
count_vowels("pear tree")
count_vowels("o a kak ushakov lil vo kashu kakao")
count_vowels("tk r n m kspkvgiw qkeby lkrpbk u thouonm fiqqb kxe...(This just goes on forever)")
```

The result is,

```
5
0
4
13
16
```

Comment: This will print `1` for the string `aaaa`, what is wrong.

Comment: @JavascriptDev Sure! I know. Just I gave the information regarding of syntax errors.